# Pushing do nothing

Tags: git, ssh, server

By following this tutorial : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

I tried to push some data on my server.
Everything looks to work fine but when I do a ls on the remote file, nothing have change.

```
touch a
git add .

git commit -m "foo"
[master f8f3336] foo
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 a

git push 

Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 258 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To XX@XX.XX.XX:/git/portail.git
92c04da..f8f3336  master -> master
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Have you done `git pull` on target remote server?

Comment: I just try : git pull 
"fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree."
So i just do : git checkout master, but it keep telling me "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: What do you mean by _"I do a ls on the remote file"_?

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

- **Not likely** but you might be working on a `bare` repo. 
  A bare repo is a repository which does not have working directory.
  check your configuration to make sure you are not

  ```
  git config -l | grep core.bare
  ```
- Specify the name of the branch when you are pushing

  ```
  # specify the name of the branch you wish to push
  git push origin master
  ```

  It can also work without specifying the branch name but its better to supply it.
- Pull before you push

  ```
  git pull origin master
  git push origin master
  ```